# Custom Button style is appearing in preview but not on device

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I made a custom style for my buttons. It is perfectly appearing in Layout Preview (through Android Studio XML Preview) but when I'm running the app, the button has not the wanted borders.

Any idea of the reason(s) that may cause this ?

activity_main.xml

```xml
<style name="Button.Pink" parent="Button">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/rounded_corners_button</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundTint">@color/pink</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

styles.xml

```xml
<Button
    style="@style/Button.Pink"
    android:id="@+id/btn_sale"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top|start"
    android:enabled="false"
    android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:text="@string/sale"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
    android:visibility="gone"
    tools:visibility="visible" />
```

rounded_corners_button.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="65dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

EDIT :
Adding some pictures of renderers

What the XML Preview Layout Design shows : 
[image]

What the app shows :
[image]

Comment: Which version of api you are checking?

Comment: min 21, and target api 28

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try change this line

```
<style name="Button.Pink" parent="Button">
```

**To**

```
 <style name="Button.Pink" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button"> //AppCompat style to support backports.
```

**UPDATED**

If you are targeting min api 21 then try latest material button introduced in support library 28..

```
<android.support.design.button.MaterialButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Sale"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
    app:cornerRadius="50dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp" />
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but it is still not working. I will add some pictures to show my issue

Comment: @Kamil Check my updated answer you can simply add above material code.. Default button colour is your theme accent color.

Comment: Thank you very much, this has fixed my issue :)

Comment: @Kamil Welcome glad to help..! Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you just forgot to remove     android:visibility="gone"? :)))

Also why are you using `android:backgroundTint` and `android:foreground`?
Maybe you can do something more simple, like this

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/"
    <corners android:radius="65dp" />
</shape>
```

And also create shapes for other states and than create one selector

Comment: Thanks for answering. I have set programatically its visibile to visible. I forgot to mention that.

I'm using these both attributes to keep both my pink background color and the ripple on button touch

Answer (score -1):

Use below code I hope it will help you

**Button**

```
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_corners_button"
        android:text="Buttons" />
```

**rounded_corners_button in draweble**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
            <corners android:radius="5dip" />
            <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#00FFFF" />
            <gradient android:angle="-90" android:startColor="#8dbab3" android:endColor="#58857e" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. The code seems to be working through the layout but still not showing borders on app